# Wikipedia and cURL with PHP

Tags: php, curl, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to load information from Wikipedia with cURL and PHP, but it's not working as intended.

See my code :

```
$url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=xml&limit=1&search=stackoverflow";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'USERAGENT');
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//return $result;
var_dump($result);
```

It doesn't return anything. However, if you load the address in your browser, it works!
So I'm wondering what should I change in order to execute this cURL request well.
Thank you folks !

Answer (score 0):

The request is redirecting to https. So either reference the https uri instead or set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to true:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: Well, I did, read my code again !
I changed the value because I didn't want it exposed here, but there is still a value.

Comment: I am blind you see. After waking up, I changed my answer.